# Is span of 3 vectors a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

Let's say we have 3 vectors

$$S=\{(1,2),(3,1),(6,5)\}$$

It has 3 elements hence it belongs to $\mathbb{R}^3$

> Is the span of these elements a Subspace of
>
> i) $\mathbb{R}^4$?
> ii)  $\mathbb{R}^3$?
> iii) $\mathbb{R}^2$?

I am really confused right now is it a subspace of the above or is it not?
Or is it just that the example that I took is wrong?

Comment: "It has 3 elements hence it belongs to R3". No, this is not quite correct. They are vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$. You have $3$ vectors in the plane.

Comment: The span of any number of vectors in $\mathbf R^n$ is a subspace of $\mathbf R^n$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$S$ is a set containing three vectors, each of these belonging to $\mathbb{R}^2$ (not $\mathbb{R}^3$), because they have two real components. Moreover, every two vectors in $S$ are linearly independent (for instance, $(1,2)$ and $(3,1)$ are linearly independent), so $S$ spans $\mathbb{R}^2$.

However, $S$ is not a basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$, since a basis is a set where all vectors are linearly independent, which is clearly not the case. You may verify this by checking that there exist constants $a$, $b$ and $c$ not all zero that satisfy

$a(1,2)+b(3,1)+c(6,5)=(0,0)$

Furthermore, it is obvious that $S$ may not be a basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$, because it contains more than $2$ vectors and a basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$ must contain exactly $n$ vectors (try to prove this!).

In this context, it makes no sense to speak about $\mathbb{R}^3$ or $\mathbb{R}^4$, because the vectors we are working with are defined in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Anyway, you could use the vectors in $S$ to construct a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$ (or $\mathbb{R}^4$), by adding one (or two) extra component(s) to each of them, but the subspace that they generate (and its dimension) would depend on your choice for the new component(s) (which is completely arbitrary). For instance,

$V=\{(1,2,0),(3,1,0),(6,5,0)\}$

spans a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$ with dimension $2$.

However,

$U=\{(1,2,1),(3,1,2),(6,5,3)\}$

spans $\mathbb{R}^3$ (it is a basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$).

Comment: Thank you so much! You really helped me out a lot! Appreciate it :)

Comment: But can u tell me one thing? If we take S={(1,2),(3,1)}, then is the span of S a Subspace of R3?

Comment: No, because the vectors in $S$ do not belong to $\mathbb{R}^3$. The most basic condition for a set $U$ being a subspace of a vector space $V$ is that $U \subseteq V$, i.e. all vectors in $U$ are in $V$.